# why </script> tag in js string is being validated

Tags: javascript

I have following page

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="e01.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj={someHTML: "<script>alert('a');</script>rest of the html",  
               someOtherAttribute:"some value"};
    alert(obj.someHTML);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in someHTML attribute of my object I have `</script>` tag in a string. but browser reads this as actual close tag and closes the script element. is there anything I am missing here? (tried it in ff and chrome)

Comment: hey I found a bug in stackoverFlow. I cannot write </script> in a regular text. it is working in comments but not in an actual question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML is parsed before and independent from Javascript. The current browser behavior is that, once an open tag `<script>` is found, the browser will switch to "Script Data State" and interpret all following data as script until a `</script>` is found.

Where the `</script>` is detected doesn't matter — inside a JS string, a JS comment, a CDATA section, or even HTML comment.

You need to make the string does not look like `</script>` to the HTML parser. The simplest way is to write `<\/script>` as in [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509818/why-script-tag-in-js-string-is-being-validated/3509843#3509843)'s answer.

Comment: *Curious note:* Regarding the HTML4.01 spec, actually it should be the `ETAGO` sequence `</` the token that would terminate a `SCRIPT` element's content, but seems that most browsers are permissive, and now the de-facto standard is `"</script"`. It seems comprehensible, is really common to have for example HTML in strings e.g.: `var foo = '<span></span>';`... check [this test](http://kangax.github.com/jstests/etago_delimiter_test/).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to escape the script tag, like this: `<\/script>`

```
var obj= {
   someHTML: "<script>alert('a');<\/script>rest of the html",  
   someOtherAttribute: "some value"
};
```

---

Related post:

- [How can JavaScript make new page that contains more JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004995/how-can-javascript-make-new-page-that-contains-more-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You can either escape < and > by, respectively &lt; and &gt; or put the whole script in a CDATA section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
var obj={someHTML: "<script>alert('a');</script>rest of the html",  
               someOtherAttribute:"some value"};
    obj(some.pageButtonScript);
]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it can be this.

```
 var obj= {
 someHTML: "<script>alert('a');</scr"+"ipt>rest of the html",  
 someOtherAttribute: "some value"
 };
```

just put a space between the ending script tag, so it wont be parsed as End tag.