# Javascript - breaking up string literals... why?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry the question title is so vague, but I was looking at some code from a Job posting boards conversion tracking software and ran across this for the first time.

```
    document.write('<i' + 'mg height="1" ' +
         'width="1" border="0" ' +
         'src="' + url + '&ifr' + 'ame=0" />');
    document.write('</ifr' + 'ame>');
```

Why are they breaking up the string literal in this manner? Specifically `'</ifr'+'ame>'`

Comment: Sometimes this is used to trick software that scans JavaScript for suspicious code (like iframes redirecting to another URL)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When HTML parsers see certain tags, even when embedded in JavaScript strings, they'll be parsed immediately as those tags.

Breaking them up avoids this behavior--`<script>` is the one that usually causes problems; I agree with Mike that it shouldn't be necessary for `iframe`s (AFAIK no others, either, but I can't speak to that with any authority).

It's also a trick to avoid being trivially parsed by crawlers.

Comment: Do you have an example?  I'm pretty sure the bit about HTML parsers isn't true.

Comment: @MikeSamuel [Like this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509818/why-script-tag-in-js-string-is-being-validated) I was imprecise in my answer, and I don't think it's necessary for `iframe`s as you said, but it is for `script`. I don't recall seeing your `script` example when you first answered. But it is true for the `script` tag, which is the same thing you said, and is because of the HTML parser.

Comment: Understood.  `</script` is the only tag-like sequence of characters that need to be split inside SCRIPT elements.  `<textarea>`, `<style>`, `<title>`, `<noscript>`, `<noframes>`, etc., `<xmp>`, `<listing>` is the full set of elements that can contain (in certain contexts for `<no*>`) non-tag content.  `<plaintext>` is another special case but has no corresponding end-tag.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like cargo cult programming.

In HTML, you need to make sure that your `<script>` blocks do not contain `</script>` that you do not want to end the script.

For example,

```
<script>document.write('<script>alert(42);</script>');</script>
```

is a broken script but

```
<script>document.write('<script>alert(42);<\/script>');</script>
```

is a single well-formed script block.

In XHTML, `<script>`s don't work that way so you need to worry about `]]>` instead when you're using CDATA sections.

In either case though, splitting `</iframe>` and `<img` is unnecessary.

Comment: Cargo cult is unlikely, this is from the conversion tracking script that Indeeed.com provides.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is they are doing that in an attempt to defeat web crawlers which would ordinarily parse the static HTML looking for certain tags to scrape.