# Javascript in document.write

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can JavaScript make new page that contains more JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004995/how-can-javascript-make-new-page-that-contains-more-javascript)

I tried writing this: `document.write('<script>document.write("test")</script>');` and it displays `'); });//]]>` I believe that it's because I wrote `<script> </script>` in it, why does it happen and what can I do (I purposely want it surrounded by `<script>`?

Thanks.

Comment: generally you should try to avoid using `document.write` at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to put it in an external file (where scripts belong) or do the ugly "escaping" thing:

```
document.write('<script>document.write("test")</scr' + 'ipt>');
```

or

```
document.write('<script>document.write("test")<\/script>');
```

But really, put it in an external file, please.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence `</script>` … ends the script element. If you do this in the middle of a string, then you end up with a JS syntax error.

In a JS string, `\/` means the same as `/`, so escape the slash character to avoid having an end tag in the markup.

```
document.write('<script>document.write("test")<\/script>');
```

Comment: It works but it's not surrounded by script.

Comment: If you mean you want to write the **text** `<script>` and not the **HTML** `<script>` then you have to use entities for characters with special meaning in HTML (i.e. `&lt;` instead of `<`).

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the browser will see the `</script>` part and think it's the ending tag of your script.

To overcome this, just split it in two strings like this

```
'<script>document.write("test")</scr'+'ipt>'
```

Answer (score 0):

When the browser runs your script and encounters `</script>`  It would think your script has ended. I would have the string split up into 2 separate strings concatenated together. Or you could put your script in an external file and not run into the problem entirely. The second might be a little extra work if you're doing a small thing, but it does make it so you don't have to write anything extra or concatenate.