# What's <\/script> for?

Tags: javascript

```
<\/script>
```

This is how it is used:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I got this from initializr.

Comment: See the answers on this post: [How can JavaScript make new page that contains more JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004995/how-can-javascript-make-new-page-that-contains-more-javascript)

Comment: An explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Answer (score 5):

The backslash prevents the browser from seeing a `</SCRIPT>` tag which would end the Javascript. Javascript will eat it, so the output will be `</SCRIPT>` as desired.

Comment: You must put `</script>` and other HTML code in backticks or the markup will eat it.

Answer (score 2):

escape character to insure slash outside of the quoted text is not encoded.

Answer (score 2):

It’s simply `</script>` with the forward slash escaped so it doesn’t get automatically encoded by the `document.write()` function.